# Identifying lines of one feature class that touch another feature class with their endpoints in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, intersection, features, line

I want to find out and select the features of one feature class, which both endpoints touch another feature class. [image]

In the picture above it would be the left pink line which touches feature of another feature class on both ends.

The best would be, if there is a way to find out the right features automatically.
This question ( [Distinguishing lines that intersect from lines that touch?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23912/lines-that-intersect-vs-lines-that-touch-how-to-distinguish) ) could also be a solution, but I have difficulties using the Python Script. I want to use this as a script tool but I don't know how to select parameters. I thought they will be added automatically after adding the Python script, but it didn't work out.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you're having troubles with the solution to the other question, you'd be best served by editing the question to explain what exact difficulty you are experiencing.

Comment: Sorry. You're right.